# Inserting null columns into a scipy sparse matrix in a specific order

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix with M rows and N columns, to which I want to concatenate K additional NULL columns so my objects will have now M rows and (N+K) columns. The tricky part is that I also have a list of indeces of length N, which can range from 0 to N+K, that indicate what is the position that every column should have in the new matrix.

So for example, if N = 2, K = 1 and the list of indices is [2, 0], it means that I want to take the last column from my MxN matrix to be the first one, the introduce a null column and then put my first column as the last one.

I'm trying to use the following code - when I already have x but I can't upload it here.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
M = 5000
N = 10
pad_factor = 1.2
size = int(pad_factor * N)
x = sparse.random(m = M, n = N, density = 0.1, dtype = 'float64')
indeces = np.random.choice(range(size), size=N, replace=False)
null_mat = sparse.lil_matrix((M, size))
null_mat[:, indeces] = x
```

The problem is that for N = 1,500,000, P = 5,000 and K = 200 this code won't scale and it will give me a memory error. The exact error is:
"return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype = self.dtype, order=order) MemoryError".

I just want to add some null columns so I guess my slicing idea is inefficient, especially as K << N in my real data. In a way we can think about this as a merge sort problem - I have a non-null and a null dataset and I want to concatenate them, but in a specific order. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is due a dense-array created during the call of ```np.random.choice```. Why don't you build a new ```coo_matrix``` (look at the constructors; there is an efficient one for those position-based nonzeros), then use ```sp.hstack``` (to combine those two matrices).

Comment: When describing an error you should give at least some of the traceback, so we know where the error occurred.  Especially in the case of a memory error, most of us don't want to reproduce your problem to get that information ourselves.  @sascha has made a good guess, but I'm not going to confirm it.

Comment: @sascha, the error occurs in the `lil.__setitem__` method.  If `x` is sparse, it does `x.toarray()`.  I found the `np.zeros` line in `sparse.base` `_process_toarray_args` method.  The OP has withheld vital information!

Comment: Sascha's comment was my problem, sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I deduced in the comments, the memory error was produced in the

```
null_mat[:, indeces] = x
```

line because the `lil` `__setitem__` method, does a `x.toarray()`, that is, it first converts `x` to a dense array.  Mapping the sparse matrix onto the index `lil` directly might be more space efficient, but a lot more work to code.  And `lil` is optimized for iterative assignment, not this large scale matrix mapping.

`sparse.hstack` uses `sparse.bmat` to join sparse matrices.  This converts all inputs to `coo`, and then combines their attributes into a new set, building the new matrix from those.

### direct coo matrix construction

After quite a bit of playing around, I found that the following simple operation works:

```
In [479]: z1=sparse.coo_matrix((x.data, (x.row, indeces[x.col])),shape=(M,size))

In [480]: z1
Out[480]: 
<5000x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5000 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Compare this with the `x` and `null_mat`:

```
In [481]: x
Out[481]: 
<5000x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5000 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [482]: null_mat
Out[482]: 
<5000x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 5000 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

Testing the equality of sparse matrices can be tricky.  `coo` values in particular can occur in any order, such as in `x` which was produced by `sparse.random`.

But the `csr` format orders the rows, so this comparison of the `indptr` attribute is a pretty good equality test:

```
In [483]: np.allclose(null_mat.tocsr().indptr, z1.tocsr().indptr)
Out[483]: True
```

A time test:

```
In [477]: timeit z1=sparse.coo_matrix((x.data, (x.row, indeces[x.col])),shape=(M,size))
108 µs ± 1.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [478]: 
In [478]: timeit null_mat[:, indeces] = x
3.05 ms ± 4.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

### matrix multiplication approach

`csr` format indexing with lists is done with matrix multiplication.  It constructs an `extractor` matrix, and applies that.  Matrix multiplication is a `csr_matrix` strong point.

We can perform the reordering in the same way:

```
In [489]: I = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(10),(np.arange(10),indeces)), shape=(10,12))
In [490]: I
Out[490]: 
<10x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [496]: w1=x*I
```

Comparing the dense equivalents of these matrices:

```
In [497]: np.allclose(null_mat.A, z1.A)
Out[497]: True
In [498]: np.allclose(null_mat.A, w1.A)
Out[498]: True


In [499]: %%timeit
     ...: I = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(10),(np.arange(10),indeces)),shape=(10,
     ...: 12))
     ...: w1=x*I
1.11 ms ± 5.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

That's better than the `lil` indexing approach, though still much slower than the direct `coo` matrix construction.  Though to be fair, we should construct a `csr` matrix from the `coo` style inputs.  That conversion takes some time:

```
In [502]: timeit z2=sparse.csr_matrix((x.data, (x.row, indeces[x.col])),shape=(M
     ...: ,size))
639 µs ± 604 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

### error traceback

The MemoryError traceback should have revealed that the error occurred in this indexed assignment, and that the relevant method calls are:

```
Signature: null_mat.__setitem__(index, x)
Source:   
    def __setitem__(self, index, x):
       ....
       if isspmatrix(x):
           x = x.toarray()
       ...

Signature: x.toarray(order=None, out=None)
Source:   
    def toarray(self, order=None, out=None):
        """See the docstring for `spmatrix.toarray`."""
        B = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
Signature: x._process_toarray_args(order, out)
Source:   
    def _process_toarray_args(self, order, out):
        ...
        return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
```

I found this by doing a code search on the `scipy` github, for the `np.zeros` calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The first solution (direct coo matrix construction) was exactly what I was after for